# Авто обновление части страницы

Tags: json, javascript

Нужно обновлять кусок php кода каждые n секунд. 
Подскажите хорошее решение.=)

Answer (score 1):

Самое просто решение - сделать цикл, в котором через каждые n секунд будет отправляться post запрос на сервер и получаться новый код, который можно вставлять в нужное место

Comment: А если на ajax? 
Написал вот такую штуку

    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $("#block").load("readme.php #block"); 
    }, 30000);</script>

Но что то не грузит.

Comment: вам и говорят про аякс.

    -$("#block").load("readme.php #block");

    +$("#block").load("readme.php");